# How does one pass a callback function as a parameter in the GET request?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http, callback

And why would we pass a callback function via GET?  Noob here, and I've tried google and it failed me.  From what I'm understanding, it MIGHT look like this (and I'm not sure):

```
xhr.open("GET", "serverSideFile.php?callback=thisFunction", true);
```

help anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that you execute the JS returned by the request if the request was returning JSON data  by putting it in a `<script>` element.

something like....

```
// the request stuffs
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// detect state changes
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) { // this is completed state
        // build the script element to inject into
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";

        // put the ajax response into the script element
        s.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;

        // add it to the <HEAD>
        document.getElementByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
    }
}

xhr.open("GET", "serverSideFile.php?callback=myCallback", true);
xhr.send(null); // do that ajax


// the callback function
function myCallback(data) {
    // do blah
}
```

the return from the service would be like...

```
myCallback([{title: "item1", value: "blah1"},{title: "item2", value: "blah2"}]);
```

**EDIT:**

I guess you could also use HTML5 script async on this as well and just....

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.type = "text/javascript";
s.async = true;
s.src = "serverSideFile.php?callback=myCallback";
document.getElementByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
```

**EDIT:**
Here is an article about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: How does the myCallback get called?  Does it get called automatically because it was part of the URL? or would I need to call  it?  EDIT: wording

Comment: so... 
1. the request includes the callback in the querystring
2. the service wraps the returned json in a function call of the callback.
3. the client side js gets the response and injects it into a script tag.
4. the browser executes this code calling the call back function

Comment: Thanks!  I think things are getting clear to me.  Also, just as a clarification, I'm expecting the service to add "myCallback" in its return string, right?

Comment: So I guess, my question is.... is the coder of the server-side code supposed to parse my GET request and look for my callback function's name, and then use that name to wrap the json data?  (I'm confused about if wrapping is a default server behavior or more of an policy/etiquette followed by coders.)

Comment: Yes, exactly what you said. So if the data to be returned was the number `3`, then it would need to be returned as `myCallback(3)`.